# get latitude and longitude from google maps and set to hidden fields in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, html, google-maps, jsp

I use javascript to work with google map,i want to get latitude and longitude values and i want to set these values to hidden text fields,please solve my problem,thanks advance

```
home.jsp

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.5, 78.5),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                placeMarker(event.latLng);
            });

            var marker;
            function placeMarker(location) {
                if(marker){ //on vérifie si le marqueur existe
                    marker.setPosition(location); //on change sa position
                }else{
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({ //on créé le marqueur
                        position: location, 
                        map: map
                    });
                }
                getAddress(location);
            }

      function getAddress(latLng) {
        geocoder.geocode( {'latLng': latLng},
          function(results, status) {
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if(results[0]) {
                document.getElementById("address").value = results[0].formatted_address;

              }
              else {
                document.getElementById("address").value = "No results";
              }
            }
            else {
              document.getElementById("address").value = status;
            }
          });
        }
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
      </head>
<body bgcolor="cyan">
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="insert.jsp"  onsubmit="return validateForm()">

<div style="background-image:url(bg.jpg); ">
<center><h1><font color="red">TRAFFIC INFORMATION SYSTEM</font></h1></center><br>
</div>
<hr size="10" color="red">

<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="homepage.jsp"><img alt="homepage.jsp" src="home.PNG" style="width: 68" height="48"></a></li>
<li><a href="jaminfo.jsp"><img alt="jaminfo.jsp" src="info1.jpg" style="width: 68" height="48"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content" style="width:1200px;">
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height: 450px; float:left;"></div>
    <div style="width:400px; height: 500px; float:right; margin-top: 100px;" >
<table  cellpadding="8">
<tr>
<td align="left">
Location</td><td>   <textarea rows="4" cols="20" id="address" name="location"></textarea></td>
<tr>
<td align="right">
Expected Time
</td>
<td align="left">
<input type="text" size="3" name="time" maxlength="3">
Minutes
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden"></td><td><input type="hidden"></td>
<td><input type="image" src="submit.gif" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48"/></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div>

</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed ur code :
    
        
            var map;
            function initialize() {
            var myOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.5, 78.5),
                    zoom: 8,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

```
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                placeMarker(event.latLng);
            });

            var marker;
            function placeMarker(location) {
                if(marker){ //on vérifie si le marqueur existe
                    marker.setPosition(location); //on change sa position
                }else{
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({ //on créé le marqueur
                        position: location, 
                        map: map
                    });
                }
                getAddress(location);
            }

      function getAddress(latLng) {
        geocoder.geocode( {'latLng': latLng},
          function(results, status) {
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if(results[0]) {
                document.getElementById("address").value = results[0].formatted_address;
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                   // alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
                   document.getElementById("lat").value = latitude;
                   document.getElementById("long").value = longitude;
              }
              else {
                document.getElementById("address").value = "No results";
              }
            }
            else {
              document.getElementById("address").value = status;
            }
          });
        }
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```